# AS3 - Is there a way to write this with lesser code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to write this with lesser code? Because if I add more buttons to the menu, i would
need even more eventlisteners and functions, and it feels like there is some other way to make this.

Code:

```
    private function addMenu():void
    {
        var menu:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var resumeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var exitFullscreenButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var exitButton:Sprite = new Sprite();

        resumeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resumeButtonHandeler);
        exitFullscreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitFullscreenButtonHandeler);
        exitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitButtonHandeler);

        menu.addChild(exitFullscreenButton);
        menu.addChild(exitButton);
        stage.addChild(menu);

        menu.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - menu.width / 2;
        menu.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - menu.height / 2;
    }

    private function resumeButtonHandeler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Im the resumeButton");
    }

    private function exitFullscreenButtonHandeler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Im the exitFullscreenButton");
    }

    private function exitButtonHandeler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Im the exitButton");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the setup function (addMenu) as you have it but remove the listeners and add a new line:

```
private function addMenu():void
{
    var menu:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var resumeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var exitFullscreenButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var exitButton:Sprite = new Sprite();

    //you are missing the resume button? intentional?
    menu.addChild(exitFullscreenButton);
    menu.addChild(exitButton);
    stage.addChild(menu); // !!!

    menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMenuClick); //added line

    menu.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - menu.width / 2;
    menu.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - menu.height / 2;
}
```

And then simply create a handleMenuClick function that will be in charge of handling every click on the menu (its children):

```
private function handleMenuClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch(e.target) {
        case exitFullscreenButton:
            trace("exitFullscreenButton click");
            break;
        case exitButton:
            trace("exitButton click");
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to put the buttons as class variables, not local variables! Otherwise you won't be able to compare the references, obviously. Or you can assign them a `.name` property and then compare that (`e.target.name`)

I discourge you adding your items to the stage, btw. Always add them to your stage owner (aka your main /document/ class). (I marked it as `//!!!` in the code)

Comment: Thanks alot! This is exactly as i wanted it to be :)

Comment: But what do you mean with adding to main class?

Comment: The stage owner is your 'document class' or the main timeline- depending on your coding habits/skills. In your case it is the document class. That means that the stage adds this class (which extends either movieclip or sprite /hoho, ever wondered why? ;) / ) automatically as its child to display list. This document class should be your container for every content you add. So if you put: stage.addChild(menu) -> you are placing menu OVER any element you will ever add in your document class and its children. Of course you could just add all the content to stage but you shouldn't.

Comment: So I should do it like: this.addChild(something) in the document main class?

Comment: Is this function in the document class? Then yep, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate button creation, for example:

```
private function addButton(menu:Sprite, clickHandler:Function):void {
    var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    menu.addChild(button);
}
```

Also, you can use anonymous functions like that:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    doStuff();
});
```

But I not recommend to use anonymous functions. Maybe it will be save some lines of code, but source code will be harder to read (imho) and it can occurs some memory leaks.

Generally, I recommend you don't forget that you can split logic to different classes.

Comment: How does the function work if you want multiple buttons? Or do you mean that i have to create a function for every single button?

Comment: Yeap, it also required separate listener for every button.